# behaviour of escape characters

Tags: c, console, special-characters

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{

   printf("az\b\b");

   printf("s\ni");

}
```

above program when compiled with gcc gives output

```
sz

i
```

Can someone help us out to understand the output

Comment: Next time please format code using the `101010` button above the editor window, use the preview feature of the editor page to check your formatting, and read the editing tips to be found right of the editor window. You're a programmer. Learn to pay attention to detail.

Comment: This does not depend on C the language, but more the OS or other environment.

Answer (score 3):

That's because your console interprets `'\b'` as a backspace character.

Comment: But why is z printed after s.

Comment: Can you please explain the answer using your reasoning.

Comment: @santosh: Your program prints `az`, then moves the cursor backwards twice (now it's back at the beginning of the line), writes an `s` where the `a` used to be, goes to the beginning of the next line, and prints an `i`. The `z` is just never overridden because your program doesn't do it. I'm not sure what else to tell you. You could take an editor that has overriding mode and do this manually if you can't follow that algorithm in your head.